# Can DAX time intelligence be used without a date table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data model with the date table having 5 calendars. The 1st column of the date tavle is CalendarName.

On the report the user is forced to choose 1 CalendarName.

Since date table has multiple calendars (5), 1 day repeats 5 times. Hence the table cannot be marked as date table. So technically I don't have a date table.

In this situation is there any way I can use the time intelligence function like the following?

```
CLOSINGBALANCEMONTH(<expression>,<dates>[,<filter>])
```

1 work around is to write dax that gets month number into a variable (`varYear` and `varMonth`), and then based on these variables get the last date of the month (`varDt`), and then based on this variable evaluate the expression for that day using:

```
Calculate(<expr>,CustomDateTbl['Date']=varDt
```

Is there any other approach? For example- can I activate the auto date time intelligence and then in the dax I can use date from the fact table's date column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a date table for time intelligence to work. Simple as that.

There is nothing special about the time intelligence functions - you can write your own equivalents using slightly more verbose DAX. However, your model doesn't sound right though. Even if you have 5 calendars for the end users to choose from, you should still have a proper date table. Why do these 5 calendars not just feed into a separate proper date table?

If you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8Rm7dwM6gc), you can see Alberto use 2 dates tables and propagate the values from one to the other. It sounds like you should be doing something similar.

Comment: So CustomDateTbl to ActualDateTbl (m:1), and then ActualDateTbl to FactTbl (1:m)? What's the point of this? For example the Fiscal Year, Fiscal Week values will still need to be taken from the CustomDateTbl.

Comment: I would do CustomDateTbl 1:m ActualDateTbl 1:m FactTbl and ensure the first relationship is not active and you use DAX to move the filters across tables. Basically, exactly like Alberto's video.

Comment: Since custom date table has multiple records for the same date, how can I do 1:m on it? It must be m:m right?

Comment: Don't your end uses choose just a single calendar? If so, it sounds like 5 inactive relationships are required and you activate the correct one using DAX.

Comment: That's extra dax to be written which I think is complex compared to having 1 custom date table with 5 calendars and making m to m relationship with fact table with filter direction flowing from the custom date tbl to fact tbl. Simpler for end users to make their own reports without needing DAX cross filter knowledge.

Comment: That's PowerBI for you. If you want full control over everything, you sometimes need to write a bit of DAX. If you can simplify somehow by changing the requirements or adapting the model, then do so as long as there are no knock on impacts.

Comment: Any other questions?

Comment: Is the dax alternative given in my question correct?

Comment: Sorry - impossible for me to say without seeing your model and sample data.